# Only be able to see the url of the pictures CarrierWave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave, form-for

I'm struggling with CarrierWave.
It worked 1 month ago.
However, it became unwell suddenly, and  I can't see any pictures which I've uploaded in browzer!!

Could you tell me the reason ?

> index.html.slim

```
...
h4.h4-title.glyphicon.glyphicon-globe Psara Medical News
- @posts.each do |post|
  .container.well
    .row
      .col-lg-6
        .input-group
          span.input-group-btn
            h5.well.boy
              = post.subject
              small.pull-right= post.date
            - if post.picture.present?
              .img-responsive.well alt="Responsive image"
                = link_to image_tag post.picture.thumb.url
            - if post.video.present?
              .img-responsive.well alt="Responsive image"
                = link_to @post.video_url.to_s { image_tag(@post.video_url(:screenshot).to_s, id: "video", :alt => "screenshot") }
            .img-responsive.well alt="Responsive image"
            - if post.body.present?
              p.post_text.well
                strong= post.body
...
```

> show.html.slim

```
...
p#notice= notice
.container
  .row.well
    .col-md-6.well
      h4.input-group= @post.subject
      h5.input-group= @post.date
    - if @post.picture.present?
      .col-md-6.well
        .input-group= image_tag(@post.picture_url)
    - if @post.video.present?  
      .col-md-6.well
        .input-group= link_to @post.video_url.to_s { image_tag(@post.video_url(:screenshot).to_s, id: "video", :alt => "screenshot") }
    .col-md-6.well
      input-group= @post.body
...
```

> video_uploader.rb

```
# encoding: utf-8
require 'streamio-ffmpeg'
require 'carrierwave'
class VideoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include Cloudinary::CarrierWave

  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png mov wmv mp4 flv avi)
  end

  version :screenshot do
    process :screenshot
    def full_filename (for_file = model.logo.file)
      "screenshot.jpg"
    end
  end

  def screenshot
    tmpfile = File.join(File.dirname(current_path), "tmpfile")
    File.rename(current_path, tmpfile)
    movie = FFMPEG::Movie.new(tmpfile)
    movie.screenshot(current_path + ".jpg", preserve_aspect_ratio: :width)
    File.rename(current_path + ".jpg", current_path)
    File.delete(tmpfile)
  end
end
```

> picture_uploader.rb

```
# encoding: utf-8

require 'carrierwave'
class PictureUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include Cloudinary::CarrierWave]

  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  process :resize_to_limit => [700, 700]
  process :convert => 'jpg'

  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_limit => [300, 300]
  end

  def filename
    time = Time.now
    name = time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') + '.jpg'
    name.downcase
  end

end
```

Comment: I see you're using cloudinary module mixed in - can you confirm if it works without this? Also, are there any error messages when you upload an image?

Comment: Thank you. It worked for me. However, as I am using heroku, I think I need somewhere to host pictures and videos. Could you tell me what was wrong with cloudinary ? If you know

Comment: I haven't tried cloudinary sorry, but I was wondering if you tried this locally uploading files to the local file system and see if you still have the problems.